# Instantiating UIView from xib/nib using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I get an error `Ambiguous reference to member 'TimelineSectionHeaderView'` when I try to call this function like:

```
if let view = TimelineSectionHeaderView.instantiateFromNib() {
    return view
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class TimelineSectionHeaderView: UIView {

  @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

  class func instantiateFromNib() -> TimelineSectionHeaderView? {
      let x = UINib(nibName: "timelineSectionHeader", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? TimelineSectionHeaderView
      print(x ?? "no value")
      return x
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never tried that, so my best idea is - remove the `if let`. Have you tried a simple `let`? And if that works, how about adding things line by line to the full `if let` with `return` which you didn't include the code that says it's returning a `TimelineSectionHeaderView`. Third and final idea: your class names (which are good) suggest you may have a table view - nothing else in your question clearly states that. Have you tried every debug "idea" considering that? Can you instantiate a simple "dummy header view" with your code?

Comment: I tried without `if let` (but just using `let`) still didn't work.
However, I observed one more thing… my `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {` is not being called at all… 

At the same time function `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int ` is being called

Comment: Then that is where you start. Screw wherever this code is - you didn't mention why `return` - try a *simple* `let` someplace and see why `instantiateFromNib` isn't working. More... I just notice it spoke of `ambiguous reference` - which means you have two references the compiler cannot resolve. It like is `TimeLineSectionView`. Have you done a global search and looked at the results?

Comment: I tried your code and it works without problems, it loads the view from the xib file. Maybe there is a problem with your xib/nib file or some other part of your project.

Comment: Oh ok… I tried without `return` it still gives me the error. I did a global search and there's only one place where I define `TimelineSectionHeaderView`… It shows me that there's a duplicate declaration on the same line as first declaration…

However, it compiles and runs now…
I have a different problem now: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7a662050> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dateLabel.`

Comment: Ok… everything works now…
I still don't understand `File Owner` thing

Comment: Thanks for helping out everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line below:-

```
if let view = TimelineSectionHeaderView.instantiateFromNib() {
    return view
}
```

Create an instance method like this:-

```
func instantiateFromNib() -> TimelineSectionHeaderView? {
      let x = UINib(nibName: "timelineSectionHeader", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? TimelineSectionHeaderView
      print(x ?? "no value")
      return x
  }
```

Now inside your ViewController you might have created the outlet of `TimelineSectionHeaderView` use that `outlet` variable and then invoke it like this:-

```
if let view = timelineViewInstanceVariable.instantiateFromNib() {
    return view
}
```